# Where do I find Firefox NoScript .xpi on my system?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, plugins, paths, firefox-extensions

Ubuntu 14.04 32bit, Firefox 45.0.1 I have checked the following folders:

```
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
~/.mozilla/firefox
~/.mozilla/extensions
```

Have not found actually anything that would be what I am looking for.

UPDATE: I did a `locate *.xpi`, but could not find it, and `locate *noscript*` returns nothing. The extension is actually installed and enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `locate` was a good idea, but Firefox extensions are referred to by UUIDs, unique names rather than human readable ones to prevent different extensions from having the same name.

As NoScript's is `73a6fe31-595d-460b-a920-fcc0f8843232`, you should find:

```
locate *73a6fe31-595d-460b-a920-fcc0f8843232*
```

to be more helpful.